# Zend Framework 2 Getting Started on WAMP server

Tags: windows-7, wamp, zend-framework2

I have been trying to follow this tutorial: [Tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/overview.html)

I can't get past page 2. When I try to run the command:

```
php composer.phar create-project --repository-url="http://packages.zendframework.com" C:\wamp\www\zendTutorial
```

I get these messages:

```
[RuntimeException]...[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]<br>
The "http://packages.zendframework.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

I enabled `ssl_module` in the Apache modules and `php_openssl` in PHP extensions and a runtime error window popped up which I didn't read because I thought I would restart the server and everything would be okay.

Then I found out I had to create a private/public key pair so I followed this tutorial: [tutorial](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2008/07/enabling-ssl-on-wamp.html)

But I realized I skipped the step where I have to download `WSAS` (the 3rd application to download just to get this pig to oink) to export my pk from the keystore and I decided to put on the brakes and ask "really?" Is there a shortcut I can take to bypass all this crap so I can start with the tutorial? I've been at this for the past 3 hours and I am so fed up - it's demoralizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note Another way to install the ZendSkeletonApplication is to use github. Go to https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication ...

Try it this way. Get git and clone the repository from

> https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git

To do this, change in console (cmd.exe) to your workspace and type

> git clone https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git

It should create a subfolder ZendSkeletonApplication with the skeleton application inside.

Later when you have your skeleton application project you can run composer as described in the tutorial to get the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your advice and am a little farther. Now I'm getting this error when I nav to the site:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.' in C:\wamp\www\ZendSkeletonApplication\init_autoloader.php on line 48

Comment: I googled that error and I found a page on the Zend site that says to add the library to the PHP include path (which I have already done) and set an environment path in httpd.conf. I inserted 'SetEnv ZF2_PATH C:\wamp\www\Zend\library" into the httpd.conf file and it worked (in case anyone else is having this problem). Thanks for the help!

Comment: The error message already sais you what to do. You have to open the console (cmd.exe) and navigate to your projects path (cd C:\wamp\www\ZendSkeletonApplication) and then run (type in the console) "php composer.phar install". This should install all dependencies including ZF2.